# How to make enemy follow path in grid

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, path-finding

How can I make enemy follow path based on grid ?[like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tr8FH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a path finding algorithm for your enemy prefabs. I would recommend using the A* path finding, it's very useful specially for 2D games which I see from the screenshot is what you are using. Luckily there's already a pretty good implementation for it you can find here: https://www.arongranberg.com/astar/

There's a pro paid version of it that can get a bit pricey but I'm assuming you're pretty new to game development and Unity so the free version found on the site should be more than enough.

Hope that helps.